# C# Linq OrderBy filtering null or empty values to be last

Tags: c#, linq, expression

I try to make my custom orderby extension method, i successfully worked my code but in addition i want to list null or empty or zero values last in result, anyone can help me about that issue ?

Here is my extension method to orderby

```
    public static IQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> q, string SortField, bool isAsc)
    {
        //var nullExpr = Expression.Constant(null, typeof(T));
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");
        var prop = Expression.Property(param, SortField);
        var exp = Expression.Lambda(prop, param);
        string method = isAsc ? "OrderBy" : "OrderByDescending";
        Type[] types = new Type[] { q.ElementType, exp.Body.Type };
        var mce = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), method, types, q.Expression, exp);
        return q.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(mce);
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Without using an extension method....

Create a custom `IComparer<string>` to check the empty values before using the default `String.Compare`. The first checks will return -1 instead of 1 or 1 instead of -1, if using the standard string comparison.

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns -1 instead of 1 if y is IsNullOrEmpty when x is Not.
/// </summary>
public class EmptyStringsAreLast : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(y) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
            {
                return -1;
            }
            else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(y) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                return String.Compare(x, y);
            }
        }
 }
```

Pass your `EmptyStringsAreLast` comparer into the `OrderBy` of Lambda expression. In this solution teams who have entered the race should appear alphabetical order, but the unaffiliated race entries should appear at then end.

```
var entries = repository.Race.Where(e => e.EventId == id)
                          .OrderBy(e => e.TeamName, new EmptyStringsAreLast())
                          .ThenBy(e => e.LastName)
                          .ThenBy(e => e.FirstName);
```

Answer (score 52):

The simplest way is to use

```
OrderBy(e => String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.TeamName)
```

This doesn't require any extension method or custom `IComparer` implementation etc.

```
var entries = repository.Race.Where(e => e.EventId == id)
                      .OrderBy(e => String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.TeamName))
                      .ThenBy(e => e.LastName)
                      .ThenBy(e => e.FirstName);
```

Comment: But for this you have to add `.ThenBy(e => e.TeamName)`, too. `.OrderBy(e => String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.TeamName))` will only sort by the boolean result and not by the content itself.

Comment: Not sure why this is not the accepted answer! Looks perfect! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This answer is perhaps what you were originally looking for - using your generic extension method:

```
    public static IQueryable<T> OrderByFieldNullsLast<T>(this IQueryable<T> q, string SortField, bool Ascending)
    {
        //We are rebuilding .OrderByDescending(p => p.SortField.HasValue).ThenBy(p => p.SortField)
        //i.e. sort first by whether sortfield has a value, then by sortfield asc or sortfield desc

        //create the expression tree that represents the generic parameter to the predicate
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");

        //create an expression tree that represents the expression p=>p.SortField.HasValue 
        var prop = Expression.Property(param, SortField);
        var hasValue = Expression.Property(prop, "HasValue");
        var exp = Expression.Lambda(hasValue, param);

        string method = "OrderByDescending";
        Type[] types = new Type[] { q.ElementType, exp.Body.Type };
        var orderByCallExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), method, types, q.Expression, exp);

        //now do the ThenBy bit,sending in the above expression to the Expression.Call
        exp = Expression.Lambda(prop, param);
        types = new Type[] { q.ElementType, exp.Body.Type };
        method = Ascending ? "ThenBy" : "ThenByDescending";
        var ThenByCallExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), method, types,orderByCallExpression, exp);


        return q.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(ThenByCallExpression);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on [Dave Anson's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2031774/dave-anson) answer, you can user [Comparer.Create()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/hh737198(v=vs.110).aspx) to create the Comparer from a lambda. Here's an example that sorts `unsorted` by its `myString` string fields, with `null` or empty strings appearing last.

```
var sorted = unsorted.OrderBy(x => x.myString, Comparer<string>.Create((x, y) => { 
             if ( string.IsNullOrEmpty(y) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)) return -1;
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(y) &&  string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)) return +1;
        else return string.Compare(x, y);
    }))
```

(To put them first, switch the signs on the `1` constants)

Answer (score 0):

it works for me:

```
    private static IQueryable<T> GetOrderQuery<T>(this IQueryable<T> q, BaseFilterCollection filter)
    {
        q = q.OrderBy(GetExpression<T>(filter.SortField));

        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");
        var prop = Expression.Property(param, filter.SortField);
        var exp = Expression.Lambda(prop, param);
        string method = filter.SortDirection == SortDirectionType.Asc ? "ThenBy" : "ThenByDescending";
        Type[] types = { q.ElementType, exp.Body.Type };
        var rs = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), method, types, q.Expression, exp);
        return q.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(rs);
    }

    private static Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetExpression<T>(string sortField)
    {
        ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");
        Expression prop = Expression.Property(param, sortField);

        var info = typeof(T).GetProperty(sortField, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        Expression exp = Expression.Equal(prop, info.PropertyType.IsValueType 
            ? Expression.Constant(Activator.CreateInstance(info.PropertyType)) 
            : Expression.Constant(null));

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(exp, param);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to complicate, the easiest way is to do something like this:

```
YourList.OrderByDescending(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.value)
```

Use OrderByDescending or OrderBy depending on if you want to see empty strings in the beginning or last.

Regards