# First OrderBy's results empty strings as last in dynamic OrderBy

Tags: c#, linq

I have `List<Tuple<string[], SolidColor>> ExcelData` as my list.
I can order `ExcelData` with LINQ's functions OrderBy and ThenBy and add `EmptyStringsAreLast` function to OrderBy which I found from this guy (https://stackoverflow.com/a/14641992/11848085).
Code looks like this:

```
ExcelData = ExcelData
    .OrderBy(arr => arr.Item1[2], new EmptyStringsAreLast())
    .ThenBy(arr => arr.Item1[1])
    .ThenBy(arr => arr.Item1[0])
    .ToList();
```

That works as long as I don't want to use dynamic OrderBy. If I use dynamic OrderBy, like this one (This one requires `System.Linq.Dynamic` or `System.Linq.Dynamic.Core`), I can't possible figure out any way possible to add that `EmptyStringsAreLast()` function to that first argument (`Item1[2] ASC`). (https://stackoverflow.com/a/8660293)

```
ExcelData = ExcelData.AsQueryable()
    .OrderBy("Item1[2] ASC, Item1[1] ASC, Item1[0] ASC")
    .ToList();
```

Is there a way to do something like this?

```
ExcelData = ExcelData.AsQueryable()
    .OrderBy("'Item1[2] ASC, new EmptryStringsAreLast()', Item1[1] ASC, Item1[0] ASC")
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Since `EmptyStringsAreLast()` is not dynamic, can you not do the dynamic part and then apply the `EmptyStringsAreLast()` to the result?

Comment: Off topic but I would make a custom type instead of `Tuple<string[], SolidColor>` so the code is easier to read. Then I would have `List<CustomType>` instead of `List<Tuple<string[], SolidColor>>`

Comment: How do I benefit from `List<CustomType>`, if I use it rathen than this `List<Tuple<string[], SolidColor>>`?
Edit. Just read that it's easier to read, I assume that can't be only reason for that.

Comment: I don't thing that applying `EmptyStringsAreLast()` to result works as in my program, there's 3 columns I want to order by.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I managed to figure it out. By adding `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Item1[2])`, it sorts null or empty as last.

Like this one

```
ExcelData = ExcelData.AsQueryable()
      .OrderBy("String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Item1[2]), Item1[2] ASC, Item1[1] ASC, Item1[0] ASC")
      .ToList();
```