# Make string concatenation with two parameters xaml

Tags: c#, string, xaml, replace, tostring

I have two examples of code I wrote. The main idea of this, that I have to params `ProtocolNumber` (string) and `CreationDate` (DateTime).

In the first piece of code, I tried to connect those two together in an array as a string and after that called `string.join. ordered by desc by date`.

What I want to ask: is it ok to twice call `CreationDate.ToString()`? Maybe there is a better solution for that. Maybe arrayList is better for multiple data types? Anyways I need to convert dateTime to string.

```
string[] relatedTaskTemplate = new[] { this.TaskReport.ProtocolNumber, this.TaskReport.CreationDate.ToString()};

string relatedTaskHTML = string.Join(", ", relatedTaskTemplate.OrderByDescending(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(TaskReport.CreationDate.ToString(DateTimeFormats.DateTimeFormat))).ToArray());

consultationProtocol = consultationProtocol.Replace("{{ProtocolNumber}}", relatedTaskHTML ?? "&nbsp;");
```

This is my second attempt. Using if statement.

```
string relatedTaskTemplate = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.TaskReport.ProtocolNumber)
                        ? ""
                        : this.TaskReport.ProtocolNumber + "&nbsp;";

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.TaskReport.ProtocolNumber) && this.TaskReport.CreationDate.ToString("yy-MM-dd") != "&nbsp;")
{
    relatedTaskTemplate = relatedTaskTemplate.Insert(relatedTaskTemplate.Length, ", ");
}

consultationProtocol = consultationProtocol.Replace("{{ProtocolNumber}}", relatedTaskTemplate ?? "&nbsp;");
```

There are some issues with two params connecting together. Once, it's showing only `protocolNumber`, other time, only a date. But I need to figure out-  if there is a data, that shows a list with them; if no data, then nothing.

Final result displays as html. Like "my code: 1234 01.12.2021, 4321 02.12.2021"

Comment: `OrderByDescending(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(TaskReport.CreationDate.ToString(DateTimeFormats.DateTimeFormat))).ToArray())` Are you aware that you are odering on a bool value?

Comment: regarding to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13604630/c-sharp-linq-orderby-filtering-null-or-empty-values-to-be-last Somehow tried to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution:

```
                    string joinedString = string.Empty;

                    foreach (var task in this.TaskReport.RelatedTaskList
                        .GroupBy((task) =>
                            new
                            {
                                task.ProtocolNumber,
                                task.CreationDate
                            })
                        .Select((group) => group.First())
                        .OrderBy((task) => task.ProtocolNumber)
                        .ThenByDescending((task) => task.CreationDate))
                    {
                        joinedString += relatedtasks.Replace(
                            "{{RelatedTaskProtocolNumberDate}}",
                            string.Join(
                                " ",
                                new string[]
                                {
                                    task.ProtocolNumber,
                                    task.CreationDate.ToString(DateTimeFormats.DateFormat)
                                }.Where((item) => !item.IsNullOrEmptyOrWhiteSpace()))
                               );  
                    }
                    consultationProtocol = consultationProtocol.Replace("{{RelatedTaskProtocolNumberDate}}",joinedString ?? "&nbsp;");
```